# I want to connect a php class library one server to another

Tags: php, class

I am creating a `php` class library and want to place this on my own server and related the application code placed on another server. Now I what I need is to synchronize them ie the class library could be accessed by the application(s) on the other server.

How to provide a solution so that other application(s) could access my library.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: When you say 'synchronize' do you mean the files or want the applications to communicate together? WebServices would be the way to go, i.e. REST/SOAP

Comment: Yes i tried to include library path but error occur http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0;

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to access this library, but you can't access it like the other local libraries or classes. The good way is to use web services.

A good solution is to use SOAP. PHP provides good API for SOAP, which enables you to create SOAP server and client very easily.

You will create a SOAP web server at the library end (on the server where the library is placed), and expose all the functions to the web service which you need to access. This is a very good solution and easy to use. You can find a good SOAP in PHP article here

http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Using-SOAP-with-PHP/

And also read these

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657980/how-to-make-web-service-in-php

[php web service example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242355/php-web-service-example)

and this

http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/

Also another way is to use xml and JSON. Please read this good article.

http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Please do more research and ask Mr. Google several times, and you will get a good solution according to your needs.

Hope this will help you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include a file from a different domain.

So that's cross domain.

If you want to use the functions via ajax you can use JSONP.