# connect a class library to application code with a .dll file

Tags: php, class, communication

I want to connect my class library to my application code with a .dll file which id placed in a system on different location and all  code to application code mapping are defined in a .dll file.

PHP_LIBRARY -> sessing.dll -> APPLICATION_CODE.

Is it possible.

Comment: I guess you could build a PHP module, but to what end? What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to connect a php class library one server to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516017/i-want-to-connect-a-php-class-library-one-server-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [w32api extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.w32api.php) which allows you to import functions from dlls. Worked ok for me in the past but its [pecl page states](http://pecl.php.net/package/w32api): "This package is not maintained"
There's also the [COM/.net extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) - in case you have com objects.

And then there's the [Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator (SWIG)](http://www.swig.org/) which helps you to compile existing libraries as extensions for other languages including php.